# How to copy archived artifacts from multiple child jobs parallel to parent jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

trying to call only one child job as a loop for 10 times using parallel from parent jenkins job and each child job is creating archived artifact but unable to copy archived artifact to parent job at some folder and concatenate all 10 child jobs archive artifact to one archived artifact in parent job. below is the code using declarative pipeline in parent job.

```
   stage ('Create Local Queues'){
            steps {
                
                
                script {
                         ENVNUM_LIST = readFile("${WORKSPACE}/cfg/env.lst").split("\n")
                     ENTITY_LIST = readFile("$WORKSPACE/cfg/NSCC").split("\n")
                         
                         ENVNUM_LIST.each {                      
                             String env_num ->
                                  ENTITY_LIST.each {
                                  String entity_name ->
                             
                                  
                                echo "executing queue creation "
                                       def childjob = 
                                   {
                                   build job: 'jobname',wait:false,parameters: [
                                                
                                             string(name: 'env', value: "${params.env}"),
                                            string(name: 'ParentBuildTag', value: "${BUILD_TAG}"),
                                             string(name: 'env_num', value: "${env_num}"),
                                                                                    
                                              ]
                                                        
                                            print "Build number = " + childjob.number           
                                 
                                 }
                                 
                                 parallel childjob
                                
                                copyArtifacts filter: 'output/createqueues.txt', projectName: 
                               'jobname', selector: specific("${childjob.number}"), target: output
                            archiveArtifacts "output/createqueues.txt"
```

Below is the error from Jenkins console, can someone please advise anything missing. Thank you

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got 
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@59cee532
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.singleParam(DSL.java:722)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:710)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:644)
```